# Angular not a known element error

Tags: angular, electron, quill

I'm using Angular and Electron now.

I've imported `ngx-quill` through my module file.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    ~~~,
    QuillModule
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And I imported `Quill` from my main component file

```
import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill/src/quill-editor.component';
import Quill from 'quill';
```

And I used the `quill-editor` component within my html template

`<quill-editor></quill-editor>`

And I got an error like :

```
'quill-editor' is not a known element:
1. If 'quill-editor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'quill-editor' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: Do you only have the `AppModule` or do you have other modules as well in your own code?

Comment: `import { QuillEditorModule } from 'ngx-quill-editor';` try importing this in your main.module file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've solved this issue by importing `QuillModule` on right module file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    QuillModule
],
```

needs to be added to the module where you actually use components of the imported module.
It is not enough to import the module in `AppModule` or some other module that is not imported directly into the module where you are using the editor component.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **shared module** and add QuillModule to import and export section of that, then append shared module to every module that you need to use Quill editor

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [        
    QuillModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  exports: [
    QuillModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to add formControlName (if you use reactive forms):


In my case - it helped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).